# USB Controller on Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-extension, usb, google-chrome-os

Pretty new to ChromeOS as have tried googling but can't find anything of how to write something to control my [USB Nes Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002YVD3KM) to use it pretty much as a keyboard to play emulators online, much less system demanding than running it all through linux.

Answer (score 0):

that product page doesn't say how the device presents itself to the OS.  is it a keyboard ?  if so, it should "just work" ...

you can find out by plugging it in and then going to chrome://system and look at the `lsusb` and `dmesg` output.  or look at [this page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3293821) for getting a system debug log.

if it is an arbitrary device, there is the [Chrome USB API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb), but that only works for dedicated apps.  i don't think you can write an interface as an extension which would allow working with any website.